# Android Studio APK Error: Invalid Keystore Format

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to build an app in Flutter but have come across a big issue. In order to enable app check, sign up using Facebook, etc. I need to get my SHA-1 fingerprint. I have tried to get it by running gradlew signingReport in the terminal of Android Studio; however, I get the following error:

"failed to read key androiddebugkey from store invalid keystore format"

I've read previous posts relating to this but nothing has been able to help me. If anyone could be of assistance, that would be great :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By deleting the keystore file itself.
 Android Studio will generate a new one, which don't have the same error.

Comment: It does not allow me to do so. When I go in to delete it I receive an error that says it is in use. I'm not sure what's using it and I don't have anything actively running or open that I know of

Comment: Try Ctrl+Alt+Del and go to task manager. If any program related to android studio running  close it.